# Is there a screen recording app that saves as .gif?

Tags: software-rec, screen-capture, gif

I have a blog, and sometimes I'd like to show my readers something specific about computers.

I've seen a lot of screen recording software, but all seem to save as video files.

Do any save as an animated GIF? I know how to transform a small video into a .gif, but I believe that I could make a smaller file if the .gif was created directly.

I'd like to be able to make something like this (from Codinghorror's "[Invisible Formatting Tags are Evil](https://blog.codinghorror.com/invisible-formatting-tags-are-evil/)"):

[image]

Comment: for Linux/POSIX: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35404/14305

Comment: My 7 years old question is marked as duplicate of a 6 years old question :D

Comment: @Manu If it's any consolation, I've just upvoted you for being first. Thanks to Janus for the Unix link.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Camtasia](https://www.techsmith.com/video-editor.html). If you scroll down, [in the comments Jeff says](https://discourse.codinghorror.com/t/invisible-formatting-tags-are-evil/826/22):

> > Please, tell what tool you did use to 
> >     make that kind of gif-based animated demo ?
>
> In this case, it's Camtasia, but I've
>   used gif-gif-gif before for similar
>   effects. Check out the Donation Coder
>   roundup of screencasting tools for
>   more options:
>
> http://www.donationcoder.com/Reviews/Archive/ScreenCasting/
>
> Jeff Atwood on May 9, 2006 9:02 AM

Answer (score 7):

To capture screen shots I find [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) is very good (and it is free). Animated GIF support is available in the [Cropper Plugins](http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Works fine on Windows 7. Only downside is it won't record the mouse cursor.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy: you can activate mouse cursor capturing in options: http://j.mp/19t37BM

Comment: Cropper doesn't have a very smooth user experience. The area selection window gets in the way during capture. If you hide that you have trouble starting and stopping capture. It crashes sometimes. Etc etc.

Comment: Same experience -- it captures it's own window for the first few seconds until you hide it (and at the end again until you unhide it).

Comment: I ended up writing "Gifferly" for all my gif capture needs ;-)

Answer (score 1):

When I have done this in the past, I always would do it in a two stage process. The easiest way to do this is use an application that records the video you want to convert into a GIF and then the second part of the process is to convert the video into a GIF image.

There are good desktop/screen capture utils however I recommend either [Capture Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8090)

[Animake](http://www.shareup.com/AniMake-download-24513.html)  will convert an mpg video into a GIF file.

Comment: Capture Fox ceased development (stuck at Firefox 6). Anyway, was it capable of recording the screen outside of Firefox?