# Animated GIF of recorded screen activity

Tags: screen-recorder, animated-gif

How can I make an animated GIF from recorded screen activity? For example, this GIF that I found is remarkably small:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NOTE : As pointed out by @richard's comment, this **answer is outdated**. 'All-in-one' alternatives in other [answer](https://superuser.com/a/856286/153937) and comment below.

There is no free "All-in-one solution" for screen recording in gif. You can use any screen recorder to capture in video format and then use some tools to convert video file to gif.

One possible solution:

1. Use **[CamStudio Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/camstudio_portable)** to record your screen activities to AVI.
2. Use **[VirtualDubMod](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/virtualdubmod/VirtualDubMod/VirtualDubMod%201.5.10.2/VirtualDubMod_1_5_10_2_All_inclusive.zip?use_mirror=kent)** to convert the AVI to a sequence of images (PNG).
3. Use **[Easy Graphic Converter](http://www.etrusoft.com/graphic-converter/graphic-converter.exe)** to convert the PNGs to GIFs.
4. Use **[UnFREEz](http://www.whitsoftdev.com/unfreez/)** to create an animated GIF from the images.

Source: [Screen recording in animated .gif format](https://superuser.com/questions/81826/screen-recording-in-animated-gif-format-no-sound-needed).

Comment: This answer is out of date, there are at least two all-in-one solutions: licecap and ScreenToGif.

Comment: @Richard - Thanks Richard, I added a note. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

[ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com/) is a free app for Windows to record directly to an animated GIF.

You simply have to position the transparent window above the content you wish to record and then it provides the necessary tools to remove frames, adjust the animation speed and add overlays.

Comment: This works well. AVI files it produces should probably be converted in VLC for better space efficiency.

Comment: **ScreenTo*GIF*** already produces ***GIF**'s*... It's *capable* of saving the GIF's as AVI's, but I'm not sure why one would do that with the intention of converting it back, plus the GIF's are already extremely efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good results with [FastStone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) (saves as WMV), combined with [Movie to Animated GIF Converter](http://www.evanolds.com/movtogifsimple.html). An online conversion site such as http://www.video2gif.net may also help.

Edit: If I'm not mistaken, [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) (not the same as CamStudio) can output recordings as animated GIFs directly.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/) (for Windows). It has a lot of screen capture tools and one of which is to capture screen activity in GIF format.

Here's a GIF that I captured using ShareX on the main ShareX window:
[image: ShareX GIF capture]

---

The only thing missing is the feature to add overlays to the rendered GIFs, if you want that you can use [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) as stated in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/856286).