# LibreOffice Writer: How to apply strikethrough text formatting?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Version: LibreOffice 4.0.2.2

Is it possible to apply strikethrough text formatting in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

Select what you want to strikethrough, rightclick,  style and select strikethrough. I believe this works the same way on every modern wordprocessor I've come across

Comment: A bit late to the party, but may I ask how you created that GIF?

Comment: I used [licecap](http://superuser.com/a/657800/10165) - you can see an example of me [using it in this answer](http://superuser.com/a/657800/10165), recorded using licecap.

Comment: An explanation GIF - you sir are a genius!

Answer (score 9):

To add the option to the tool bar, right-click the tool bar, then click "configure". Then click "add" and browse to "format", then "strikethough" and click "add". (You can move it next to the underline button by marking it and using the arrows under "modify".)

Comment: This should be enabled by default... Please @libreoffice?

Comment: Thanks, I come back to this answer every time I install LO. This should be the accepted answer. BTW the Menu item is now "Customize Toolbar...", and no longer "configure".

Answer (score 1):

In the Character formatting dialog box, change the value of the Strikethrough pulldown on the Font Effects tab.

Comment: Ah.. that reminds me, I totally forgot about the menubar, I'm trying out Ubuntu 13.10 and forgot the topmost application titlebar morphs into menubar when mouse hovers over it. I was wondering why there were only toolbar icons available in Writer...

Answer (score 1):

I do it in a little different way than adding borders.

**Here are the steps:**

1. Write your text
2. Press Tab
3. Click in the top right corner of your horizontal scale to add a tab stop.
4. Now, double-click the tab-stop. It'll open the configuration window.
5. Select your tab fill character and voila, it works just as expected!

[image]