# Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Windows 10?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

I am trying to install VirtualBox guest additions on Windows 10 technical preview, and am getting the following error:

[image: Cannot be installed]

I imagine I am not the only one having this issue, is there any way to force it to install?

Comment: You actually got it to install on VirtualBox? o_O

Comment: Yup. Just pick windows 8 (NOT OTHERS) as the vm type on a suitable host. Also runs fine on KVM, and vmware.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: For me, it installed using `Other Windows` as the VM type (http://i.imgur.com/hNCwJVG.png). Maybe the host OS matters? I use Kbuntu 12.04 (32 bit).

Comment: hm. Maybe cause I'm running a 64 bit guest on a 64 bit system on mine.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek He's specifically asking about the installing the VirtualBox Guest Additions in the guest, not installing the OS in a VM.

Comment: I was replying to kino's comment rather than the question. My answer proper is below.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use of Windows Compatibility settings (or use `/force`) will **not** work: installer will run, but with no real effects.

Install VirtualBox 4.3.18 or newer. It has [improved compatibility](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) with Windows 10.

**Note**: Menu `Help` > `Check for updates` may not reflect the newest as being the latest.  Download it manually instead.

## Download of New Versions

**Windows Host**: Download from [Virtualbox Download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) page for latest.

**Ubuntu Host**: run the following commands to register the virtualbox.org repository with the package manager and update from it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial contrib"
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-6
```

If you prefer, you can install the oldest `virtualbox-5.2`.

According to your distribution, replace `xenial` with any other Ubuntu release, like `zesty`, `yakkety`, `xenial`, `vivid`, `utopic`, `trusty`, `raring`, `quantal`, `precise`, `stretch`, `lucid`, `jessie`, `wheezy`, or `squeeze`.

**Others**: Check the download page [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: Thank you. VitualBox 4.3.18 works with Windows 10. Do you know, why checking for a new version from VirtualBox menu shows me that latest version is already installed, but it is not?

Comment: For Macbook Pro running OSX 10.9.2: Right-click VBoxWindowsAdditions-amd64.exe in the Windows 10 VM, choose properties and set the compatibility to Windows 7. Then "Direct 3D Support (Experimental)" won't be checked and you can proceed without install error.

Source: https://4sysops.com/archives/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 51):

It's a preview version, so I suspect it's doing naive version checking. An update for VirtualBox or Windows 10 should do the trick eventually.

For now, right click on it, select *Properties*,  the *Compatibility* tab, and select *Windows 8* compatibility there. Much easier than using the compatibility troubleshooting I did initially.

[image]

However, the drivers don't *actually* seem to work once installed, so an update would probably be needed. (Can't believe I actually missed that.) Once again, it's a preview version, and it doesn't quite work right.

Comment: Cheers, yeah I ended up re-installing on vmware which worked much better :)

Comment: Nice visual, very clear answer! +1

Comment: It works alright for me sans additions. Also seems to work alright on KVM on another box.

Comment: Is there some tool to create animations like this without too many steps?

Comment: @Kamil: [licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) as per [my answer here](http://superuser.com/questions/81826/how-do-i-create-a-gif-screencast-in-windows/657800#657800) on windows (though it also works on wine). [silentcast](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11702/125) on linux.

Comment: Why do people click `Apply` and then `OK`?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea either. Pavlovian conditioning?

Comment: Works fine for me without additions.  Definitely some under the hood changes on 10.  I'm having problems installing an application that made the transition from Vista to 7 to 8 without any problems.

Comment: This works to get the installer running, but then I get a BSoD when it tries to install the Graphics Driver.

Comment: Wierd. The *installer* ran, and the install process worked but the video and chipset drivers won't start for me. Its a prerelease so... occationally stuff dosen't work

Comment: So bad a BSoD it becomes BaGSoD (Black and Green Screen of Death)

Comment: Doesn't work for build 9860. VirtualBox 4.3.18 works with this build.

Comment: Getting the same problem in the latest 9926 build - the guest additions install, but don't seem to actually function

Comment: @benjymous Same here...

Comment: Wow - what did you use to make the animated gif?

Comment: [Licecap](http://superuser.com/a/657800/10165) - friend of mine likes [screen to gif](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) better tho. I find it makes processes like this so much clearer. I've actually mentioned it and silentcast further up in the comments thread

Answer (score 23):

Use the Force...

```
VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe /force
```

Comment: This worked, but also locked up my Windows 10 TP vm after a reboot