# Installing VB Guest Additions for Windows 10 Crashes Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, crash, guest-additions

After successfully installing Windows 10 on Virtual Box, I tried to install VB Guest additions on Windows 10 (using the *[Windows 8 compatibility](https://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10)* trick). Though this resulted in a crash midway the installation.

Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Information in the crash would be nice

Comment: report this in the VirtualBox forum. I use Vmware and here it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another poster asked the same thing on another SE thread. Of course the additions package will run when forced using using compatibility. But it will either halt during the install or the OS will crash (I tried twice). Forcing a driver to install is never supported and I doubt the folks at Virtualbox/Oracle would help.

You will have to wait until Windows 10 is officially supported by Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Enable 3D & 2D Acceleration in the VirtualBox settings. 
I also installed the guest additions in a compatibility (windows 8) mode