# Virtualization on Windows 10 not working

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10-preview

When trying to install VirtualBox on Windows, I got the following error. The version is VirtualBox-4.3.20-96997-Win. I have reviewed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10) question and it's not the same issue. 
[image]

More info just says that the installer is not recognized. It also gives the "run anyway" option.It says "common.cab" is corrupted. I've downloaded 4.3.18 (The check sum is identical), and the installer finished but some how breaks the WiFi driver (connected but no network). The program also doesn't run for no apparent reason and I've tried several compatibility options.

Comment: Does it give any specifics in the "More info" link?

Comment: I have to wonder if your download is corrupt. No way a genuine VirtualBox installer would be *unrecognized* (unless perhaps Microsoft's SmartScreen service was temporarily broken).

Comment: This particular problem has to do with the reputation of the file nothing more.

Comment: That was fixed. The point of this question though is any solution for Virtualization on Windows 10

Comment: Sorry, we don't do software recommendations on Super User. It sounds like your download is corrupted. Note that VirtualBox installs additional network adapters and it may cause the "No network" icon to appear, but it doesn't mean that networking doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not looking for a recommendation just any Virtualization solution which works on windows 10 will do. What I'm describing are symptoms of virtual box. I know what no network mean, I meant that there is no ping to my home nat or anything until i uninstall virtual box. 

I still see this as a valid question.
the file is not corrupted, the check-sum is identical.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is a Windows SmartScreen warning. It doesn't recognize the file yet and thus doesn't want you to run it.

**Click *More info* to reveal a <kbd>Run Anyway</kbd> button**.

You could also disable SmartScreen completely if you feel like a superuser, but for most people it's best to just leave it enabled and bypass warnings once in a while.

Comment: This is the correct solution to get around the SmartScreen warning, but it would be wise to first verify the hash of the VirtualBox installer exe just to be sure it's not corrupt or compromised. https://www.virtualbox.org/download/hashes/4.3.20/SHA256SUMS

Comment: it still doesn't work see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Note, I realize this question is a month old or so, but it applied then and applies in general:

Win 10 is currently beta/preview software, and as such you should be aiming to use the latest version of VB to ensure it's got the most compatibility. 4.3.18 is old (released 10-10-2014, ~4 months before your post), as of today they are currently on 4.3.24 (released on Mar 2, 2015). Try that version (or whatever's the latest offered when you get there).

See: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

For example in version 4.3.22's notes (Feb. 12, 2015):

> Windows Additions: some fixes for recent Windows 10 Previews