# How to install Guest Additions in Windows 10 on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, guest-additions

I just installed Windows 10 RTM on my VirtualBox and I wanted to install Guest Additions. I inserted virtual CD with it and during installation the graphics crashed and since then (even after reboot) I can only see a black screen. I'm reinstalling OS but how can I install properly Guest Additions? My computer is running on i5 4th generation (if that's relevant) with it's integrated graphic card.

P.S. I'm not getting any modals with errors.

Comment: Does VirtualBox report full compatibility with Windows 10, if it does not, then the answer is the same as the existing question.  You will need to wait until VirtualBox fully supports Windows 10.  if you are not using the current version you should be.  This is not a hard task.  It is as simple as running the installer for the additions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10)

Comment: I'm running  latest VirtualBox. When creating new VM I can choose Windows 10, so I'm pretty sure they support it.

Comment: [You shouldn't assume anything.  This is a known problem](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=69198)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: I've had enabled 3D acceleration and all I had to do to properly install Guest Additions was to turn it off.

Comment: For me it was 2D accel.