# Virtualbox can't detect any network adapter after upgrade windows 10

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I install virtualbox 5.0 in Windows 8.1 and running smoothly, but after I upgraded to Windows 10 my virtualbox could not detect any network adapter. I've tried to reinstall virtualbox with this way [Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10), success but after I reboot my laptop virtualbox could not detect again. Please help me :(
thank you

Comment: Quote from the official download page: Please be aware that Windows 10 is not yet officially supported! There are known problems with VirtualBox 5.0 on Windows 10 hosts and with Windows 10 guests. Some of the problems are fixed in the most recent test build which can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds).

Comment: Hello, I have this same problem. Does anyone know if there is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

What guest OS's do you use?
I use Windows 10 and my guest OS's are connected. In your guest settings (Virtualbox), go to network adapter, and set the attachment to NAT. If your guests are Windows 7 or later, then set the adapter type to "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop" and check "cable connected". My XP 32-bit guest's adapter type is set to PCnet-Fast III.