# Ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox cannot copy/paste

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I cannot copy and paste to or from my ubuntu VM. Here are the steps I have taken to no avail.

**In Settings:**

1. Storage > Advanced > Shared Clipboard = Bidirectional
2. Storage > Advanced > Drag'n'Drop = Bidirectional
3. Storage > Controller: SATA = Checked "Use Host I/O Cache"
4. Storage > Controller: IDE = Checked "Use Host I/O Cache"
5. Storage > Controller: SATA > Ubuntu.vdi = Checked "Solid-state drive"
6. System > Enable I/O APIC = Checked

I am on windows 10 running VirtualBox version 5.1.14 r112924. I have allocated 5 GB of memory to my VM, 20GB storage on a physical SSD, and 4 cpus of an i7-4790K.

What do I have to do to be able to copy/paste text to and from the VM?

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions?

Comment: Install the extension Pack and the guest addition . Related http://superuser.com/questions/819757/installing-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-windows-10 Extension pack https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Your two comments made this work! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by installing the Virtual Box expansion pack (can be located on the VirtualBox downloads page), and also installing the guest additions ON my VM.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, I can advice to use shared folders. I have the same problem, and solve it only wiht this. How to connect shared folder with Ubuntu, you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/161883/624634)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.