# Can't switch screen in Mouse without Borders in both directions

Tags: windows-7, laptop, windows-10, mouse

I've been using Mouse without Borders for a while to control my laptop next to my computer. I already upgraded the laptop to Windows 10 and MwB still worked well, but some weeks ago i got a new 4k screen (from now on I have 4 screens connected to my computer using a radeon and an intel graphic card), so I decided to upgrade my computer from Windows 7 to Windows 10 to use the High-DPI mode.

Now Mouse without Borders behaves quite strange. I cannot move from my computer to my laptop anymore, but I can use the laptop's touch-pad to switch to my computer and even back. I can also use Ctrl+Alt+F2 on my computer to switch to my laptop and control it, so the main communication seems to work, but once I leave the laptop's screen, i can't get back without using the Keyboard Shortcut.

I also did not disable EasyMouse and already tried reinstalling and reconfiguring MwB

**EDIT** After an update to version 2.1.5.1103 it still does not work

**EDIT 2** Maybe the problem I have asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/972135/maximized-chrome-shows-small-line-on-second-screen) causes the problem? If Windows does not define the screen borders correct, so MwB does not think I am at the end of the screen?

Comment: Some applications seem to have issues with display scaling, especially on 4K - seemingly stuff that does mouse position and screen scraping related tasks - could you try turning it off the same way I did for licecap here? http://superuser.com/questions/942469/licecap-dosent-respect-highdpi-settings-on-windows-8/942470#942470 if this works, let me know and I'll post a fuller answer for the bounty.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I just tried disabling the High DPI mode for MwB, but that does not seem to solve the problem. When disabling it for Chrome, it removes the small line mentioned in my other question (http://superuser.com/questions/972135/maximized-chrome-shows-small-line-on-second-screen), but it results in Chromes GUI being very large, so I can't really work with it (I enabled it again as i prefer the small line over the large GUI

Comment: Ahh, good thing I posted that as a comment then

Comment: Try as alternative the free [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/).

Comment: This is a question for the software manufacturer, not superuser. It's pointless offering a bounty.

Comment: @adampski I already tried that, but got no answer. Thats why i tried it here

Comment: But you're effectively asking people who have no input in the development of the software to help identify and resolve. The only people here that can help you are the people who make the software, from what you've told us the issue is clearly compatibility issues with Windows 10.

Comment: @adampski i know, but maybe someone else had the same problem and found a solution. And the bounty was to get more attention

Comment: After Win10 Anniversary update my MwB has broken too. I didn't know Input Director, it works for me. thanks @harrymc