# Maximized chrome shows small line on second screen

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, windows-10

I have multiple Monitors connected to my Computer running Windows 10 x64. One of them, my main one, is a 4k Screen and to its left, i have a full-HD one.

When I have Chrome 45 (or any other program) running maximized on the full-HD one, there is also a 1px wide line visible on the 4k screen. When I hove my mouse over this line, the cursors turns into the resize one, but I cannot resize  the window as it is maximized. Once I have another active windows placed in front of it, the line is in the background and not visible anymore.

Here is a screenshot to show my problem: 
[image: Small line]

I already tried around in the graphic card settings to check if it has something to do with overscan or similar, but nothing worked.

**EDIT** It has nothing to do with Chrome. The same problem appears when I have Word on this screen