# How to take full screen screenshot on Windows 10 with 4k monitor

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, 4k-resolution

Since I upgraded my monitor to a 4k, I can't take full screen screenshots anymore.

My current resolution is 3840 x 2160, but when I press print screen, it only takes a 2560 x 1440 portion of the screen from the top left corner.

I think it may be due to some scaling windows is doing to the UI so that everything is not too small, but I don't want to make everything small either.

I didn't find any good info on Google, only results talking about how to take a screenshot bigger than your resolution, like how to take 4k screenshots while being in 1080.

If it's related to my graphics card, I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 660 Ti and my monitor is connected through a display port.

Also, I'm talking about screenshots of desktop or common applications, not games or other fullscreen applications.

Also if I try to screenshot only an application such as a Chrome window using alt+print screen, it takes a screenshot of the right size (of the browser), but it's offset to the left and top.

Edit: I have a screenshot software installed (Purrint) that is auto-saving my screenshots, but I didn't think about it, because I was pasting my screenshots in Photoshop, turns out it was modifying the screenshot in the clipboard as well or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having worked in 4K on the very same graphics adaptor, its not your graphics adaptor. You've mentioned running a third party screenshot tool and its not working well.

Its basically due to the interaction of display scaling and software that does screen capture. You *could* go with native screenshotting tools *or* my [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/942469/licecap-doesnt-respect-high-dpi-settings-on-windows-8-and-10/942470#94247) for this question would work as a workaround.

Essentially to get purrit to work, find the executable, set it to 
disable display scaling for *that* application, and it should work fine. A longer term fix would be to bug the author to support modern display scaling and all those lovely things. Interestingly, this is probably a bug that would affect *any* non dpi aware/older screenshot/capture tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is the effect of DPI scaling of Windows. You set the scaling to 150% in the Windows display settings to make Icons larger, because with UHD the icons woul be too small for 100% scaling.

Now the resulting screen resolution is 2560 x 1440 (3840/1,5 is 2560 and 2160/1,5 is 1440).